# OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in debug mode on Jboss AS 7 and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss7.x

I am using `IntelliJ IDEA` and `JBOSS AS 7`. When I am trying to deploy my app in debug mode I occur this exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` and server is not answering. But if I am using Eclipse, there is no such problem with the same server! How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should help:

[image: vmoptions]

Just add `-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=300m` to the **VM options** field.